# Combine 2 rows to the same column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Hey so my query right now is

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [SSRS].[VolumeCustomers]
@UserID int
AS  

select 
    CaseTypeName,
    COUNT(CaseNo) as CaseCount,
    'Open' as indicator

FROM ORDERS.ApCase AC with (NOLOCK)
    join ORDERS.CaseType CT (NOLOCK) on CT.CaseTypeID = AC.CaseTypeID
    join WORKFLOW.WorkflowHistory WH (NOLOCK) on WH.EntityID = AC.CaseID and TableID = dbo.GetTableID('ApCase', 'ORDERS') and WH.Active = 1
    inner join WORKFLOW.WorkflowStep WS (NOLOCK) on WS.WorkflowStepID = WH.WorkflowStepID and WS.NextStepID is null
where (AC.Active =1 and AC.CreatedDate >= DATEADD(day,-7,getdate()) and AC.CreatedDate < GETDATE()) 
Group By CaseTypeName

union
select 
    CaseTypeName,
    COUNT(Caseno) as CaseCount,
    'Closed' as indicator

FROM ORDERS.ApCase AC with (NOLOCK)
    join ORDERS.CaseType CT (NOLOCK) on CT.CaseTypeID = AC.CaseTypeID
    join WORKFLOW.WorkflowHistory WH (NOLOCK) on WH.EntityID = AC.CaseID and TableID = dbo.GetTableID('ApCase', 'ORDERS') and WH.Active = 1
    join WORKFLOW.WorkflowStep WS (NOLOCK) on WS.WorkflowStepID = WH.WorkflowStepID and WS.NextStepID is not null
where (AC.Active =1 and AC.CreatedDate >= DATEADD(day,-7,getdate()) and AC.CreatedDate < GETDATE())  
GROUP BY CaseTypeName 
Order by CaseCount desc
```

and the out put is

```
Cytogenetics    2   All
Cytogenetics    1   Open
Flow Tech   1   All
Flow Tech   1   Open
Surgical    1   All
Surgical             1  Open
```

But i want the cytogenetics, flow tech, and surgical to all appear on the same row
example:

```
Cytogenetics    2   All 1   Open
Flow Tech            1        All      1    Open
Surgical             1  All      1        Open
```

How do I edit my query to reflect this?

Comment: Which values came from which query?

Comment: Query has `Closed`. Your output says it is `All`. Is that a typo?

Comment: Yea its a typo it should say closed sorry

Answer (score 1):

Does this work?

```
SELECT A.*, B.CaseCount, B.indicator
  FROM (<First Part of Union in Question>) AS A INNER JOIN
       (<Second Part of Union in Question>) AS B ON A.CaseTypeName = B.CaseTypeName
```

Comment: I tried this but when I add A.* it gives me the error 
"The Column prefix 'a' does not match with a table name or alias name used in a query"

Comment: I'm not sure why you'd get that, as the table alias 'A' is defined in the SQL above; It looks like ypercube's answer would be a simpler query anyway.

Comment: It seems like a valid solution to me. And sometimes this is faster (because of the JOIN). My solution has to gather all data and separate (count) them in the `CASE` in the `SELECT`phase.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    CaseTypeName,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN WS.NextStepID IS NULL     THEN Caseno END) AS CaseCountOpen,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN WS.NextStepID IS NOT NULL THEN Caseno END) AS CaseCountClosed,
    COUNT(CaseNo) AS CaseCountAll

FROM ORDERS.ApCase AC with (NOLOCK)
    JOIN ORDERS.CaseType CT (NOLOCK)
        ON  CT.CaseTypeID = AC.CaseTypeID
    JOIN WORKFLOW.WorkflowHistory WH (NOLOCK)
        ON  WH.EntityID = AC.CaseID
        AND TableID = dbo.GetTableID('ApCase', 'ORDERS')
        AND WH.Active = 1
    JOIN WORKFLOW.WorkflowStep WS (NOLOCK)
        ON  WS.WorkflowStepID = WH.WorkflowStepID
WHERE AC.Active = 1
  AND AC.CreatedDate >= DATEADD(day,-7,getdate())
  AND AC.CreatedDate < GETDATE()  
GROUP BY CaseTypeName 
ORDER BY CaseCountAll DESC
```

Comment: DUDDEEEEE THANKS MAN!!! I asked someone to explain why you count it to in the select statement.